# Percentage similarity between 2 similar datasets

Tags: python

Please how can I show the percentage similarity between 2 datasets, and also visualize this?

```
column_names = ['ItemDescription', 'Actual Changeover', 'SubStatusName', 'Production Time', 'Changeover Difference']

df1.columns = column_names

df2.columns = column_names

# Iterate over columns
for i in range(len(column_names) - 1):
    current_column = column_names[i]
    next_column = column_names[i + 1]
```

I got stuck here.

Comment: in order to compute similarity you need to define a metric. You didn't provide a metric to compare the two datasets. In your code you take the current column and the next column. So you want to compare one column with the next one? From the column names they seem to contain different type of data (string, numbers...) so it's unclear how can two columns be compared. You need to define a metric.